# how to delete one or multiple items from listview using checkbox

Tags: java, android

I am trying to delete one or multiple items from a listview that is using a custom adapter

I am using the following code below

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = listview.getCheckedItemPositions();
        int itemCount = contactList.size();

        for(int i=0; i<=itemCount; i++){
            if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
                adapter.remove(contactList.get(i));
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

I have also tried other solutions that have been posted by others asking the same questions but none seemed to have helped.

Comment: @zoe my bad, new to stack didn't know